# Can't compare two arrays of Object in Jquery, tried with different method without success

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, compare

i'm new to Jquery and i want to do a "simple" thing but all my attempts failed.
This is the problem, if have two arrays containing simple objects, they are like this :

```
arr1 = [Object { productID="41",  quantityOrdered=3}, Object { productID="42",  quantityOrdered=3}];
arr2 = [Object { productID="41",  quantityList=5}, Object { productID="42",  quantityList=4}];
```

As you can see they are simple object. I just need a way to compare if they are equal. To be more precise, i need to compare if a productID got the same quantity in arr1 (the value quantityOrdered) and arr2(the value quantityList).

I've tried different methods but all failed :/

```
if($(arr1).not(arr2).length === 0 && $(arr2).not(arr1).length === 0 )
{
  // my code here never executed
}
```

Or

```
if (JSON.stringify(array1) == JSON.stringify(array2))
{
    // my code here never executed
}
```

or that function find here : http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256BFB0077DFFD (areArraysEqual) but it returns me "True" every time....

Someone got a clue for this? I'm sure it's very easy but i can't find it out...
You can see all the code here : http://pastebin.com/4CSJDkSk

Thanks in advance for your future answers :)

Comment: Are the array indices of the objects with matching `productID`s always the same in both arrays? Like if `arr1[0].productID` has a value of 41, does `arr2[0].productID` also have a value of 41?

Comment: Right now yes, the array indices of the objects with matching productID's are always the same in both array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the values of properties of all of the objects within the arrays is by looping through the array and checking specifically which values you need to be equal. This assumes that the `productID` will match for array elements with the same array index.

```
for(var i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){
    if (arr1[i].quantityOrdered == arr2[i].quantityList) {
        // execute code for if quanityOrdered = quantityList
    } else {
        // execute code for when they are not equal
    }
}
```

If you ever have a situation where the indices of the objects with matching `productID` properties are different, then you may need to use an additional nested for loop to check the `productID` and `quantityOrdered` for every object in `arr1` against every object in `arr2`.

Comment: @Siick I'm glad I could help